# Contexto do EF mudado, mas sem atualizar estrutura da base de dados

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server

Estou usando o serviço de hospedagem grátis da [somee](http://somee.com/) em um plano gratuito. Ate ai tudo bem, tudo funcionou numa boa.

Mas depois que fiz umas mudanças no meu banco, o banco de dados deles simplesmente não funciona, fica dando erro:

> The model backing the 'EntidadesContexto' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Isso já aconteceu comigo em minha maquina local e eu resolvi usando a linha de comando:
`Update-Database -Verbose` que força o banco de dados a ser atualizado. E com isso tudo funcionou direito.

Já fiz isso diversas vezes em minha máquina local antes de colocar no ar, atualizei o banco de dados, mas mesmo assim o serviço de banco deles acusa que o meu contexto mudou e não atualizei (sendo que já fiz isso).

Ok, pesquisando [achei essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600175/the-model-backing-the-database-context-has-changed-since-the-database-was-crea) que dá como proposta de solução adicionar a seguinte linha no *Global.asax*:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourDbContext>(null);
```

Minhas perguntas são: Como isso funciona? E existe outra forma de eu resolver esse problema (já que não tenho acesso ao banco de dados por estar usando um plano *free*)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Como isso funciona?

`SetInitializer` como `null` indica ao Entity Framework que a base não possui classe de inicialização. Por padrão, é a [`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293%28v=vs.113%29.aspx), que executa todas as *Migrations* pendentes desde a última *Migration* detectada até a *Migration* mais recente.

## E existe outra forma de eu resolver esse problema (já que não tenho acesso ao banco de dados por estar usando um plano free)?

Você possivelmente não tem `EnableAutomaticMigrations` configurado na classe `Configuration` dentro de *Migrations*, ou o `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` teria resolvido seu problema.

Há três soluções:

### 1. Gerar uma *Migration* Adicional

É a solução mais simples, mas a *Migration* criada pode vir vazia. É raro, mas acontece.

### 2. Apagar o database e criar outro

Esta é mais radical. Funciona sempre, mas exige antes um backup da base e um deploy novo.

### 3. Apagar todos os registros de `__MigrationHistory` e fazer um update manual da base de testes para a produção

Esta é a solução mais ousada, e só deve ser usada se você tiver certeza de que o schema em produção está idêntico ao de desenvolvimento. Indicado pra quem não quer ter que derrubar a base pra subir outra.

Comment: O engraçado é que tenho *EnableAutomaticMigrations* setado como true. E ele não é executado... Porque será ? Nessa segunda opção seria apagar o banco que é gerado junto com a aplicação assim que a criamos ou o banco de produção ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Seria o banco de produção. Na verdade esse bloqueo à base eu acho uma coisa muito sem noção. Pra mim não serve nem como teste.

Comment: Valeu @Cigano, resolvi aqui. Apague o registro __MIgrationHistory e funcionou !

Comment: Muito obrigado me ajudou muito